# REGEX Python right quotation mark

Tags: python, regex

At first this is my REGEX until now

```
(``|,,|")([^"|^'{2}|`{2}|^,{2}]*)(''|``|")
```

I think that negation in the secound group that I setted isnt working correctly. I seperated all my negations like you can see, I dont know if that can work.

This should for example find this sentence

```
``Some question is here ,some text here''
```

but not this one

```
``Some question is here ,,some text here''
```

Im already trying to find the solution for hours but im new at Regex and I couldnt find the solution.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(``|,,|")((?:(?!"|'{2}|`{2}|,{2}).)*)(''|``|")$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgBRnA/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string/line
- ``` (``|,,|") ``` - two backticjks, commas or a double quotation mark
- `` ((?:(?!"|'{2}|`{2}|,{2}).)*) `` - any single char other than line break chars, as many as possible, that is not a `"` and does not start a `''`, two backticks, or `,,` char sequence
- ``` (''|``|") ``` - `''`, two backticks, or a `"`
- `$` - end of string/line.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TkfzBF):

```py
import re
rx = r"""^(``|,,|")((?:(?!"|'{2}|`{2}|,{2}).)*)(''|``|")$"""
texts = ["``Some question is here ,some text here''", "``Some question is here ,,some text here''"]
for text in texts:
    m = re.search(rx, text)
    if m:
        print(f"MATCHED: {text}")
```